# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable using python for " import copy"

Tags: python

```
import copy

a='ushu'
b=copy.copy(a)

print(id(a)==id(b))
```

and this give error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/python project/copy1.py", line 4, in <module>
    b=copy.copy(a)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: This is definitely not all your code. We'll need to see your code and traceback _along with the line numbers_, so please edit your question to include that information.

Comment: i am beginer in python and iam just trying the copy function so this is my whole code

Comment: What is the name of your python script?

Comment: Don't name files with the same name as standard modules.

Comment: yes i change the name.And now its working

Answer (score 4):

It seems that your code is named `copy.py` or there is a `copy.py` in the same directory. Thus, the `import copy` statement will import that file instead of the `copy` module in the Python standard library.

So to solve this problem, rename `copy.py` to something else.

Comment: yes its working thanx

Answer (score 1):

Name of your module is copy.py or there is another module in your project with this name. Just rename it

Comment: yes its working